# Mongoose - Get list of _ids instead of array of objects with _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to run following query:

```
Group.find({program: {$in: [...]}}).lean().select('_id')
```

And then **NOT** get following back:

```
[{_id: ...}, {_id: ...}, {_id: ...}, {_id: ...}]
```

**BUT** following:

```
[..., ..., ..., ...] where ... represents an _id of a Group
```

Of course I could just run the query and then loop through the Groups I get back, but I would like to do it in the query if possible, because that's probably going to be faster.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
Group.find({program: {$in: [...]}})
  .distinct('_id')
```

> **db.collection.distinct(field, query)**
>
> Finds the distinct values for a specified field across a single collection and returns the results in an array.

[Read more](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that tomorrow!

Comment: Why do you have lean() in it the distinct will only return the ids?

Comment: @ElishaSterngold I agree, it's certainly redundant - thanks for noticing, I updated my answer to reflect that.