# Mongoose deep find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, i have a collection in my MongoDB named Post, it's like this:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    creator: {
       type: ObjectId,
       ref: 'User',
       required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    post_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    view_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: [{
       type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }],
    reports: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Report'
    }],
    attachments: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Attachment'
    }],
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

And a User collection

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    course: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Course',
        required: true
    },
    school: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'School',
        required: true
    },
    access: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Access',
        required: true
    },
    classroom: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Classroom'
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

What i want is a way to do a query on Post, to get all posts that have the same classroom as the logged User (saved on session), i tried using where and find but no success in that, is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Do you mean all posts created by someone who has the same classroom as the current User? As there is no classroom field on Posts.

Comment: Yes, i want all the posts from users of the same classroom as the logged user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested query like the following:

```
User.find({classroom: req.session.user.classroom}).select('_id')
  .exec(function (err, users) {
    ids = users.map(function(user) {
      return user._id
    });
    Post.find({creator: {$in: ids}}, function(err, posts) {
      console.log(posts);
    });
});
```

That assumes that `req.session.user` is the way you have your user saved on the session object. If not, modify as necessary.

For clarification, we're mapping the ids of the users to an array called `ids` because the `$in` query condition expects an array of `ObjectIDs`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @snozza's answer, you can use `distinct('_id')` in order to get the array of IDs directly, without having to map it on the result.

See [Mongoose - Get list of _ids instead of array of objects with _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677879/mongoose-get-list-of-ids-instead-of-array-of-objects-with-id)